# Copy buffer to clipboard [new line error]

Tags: c++, winapi, buffer, clipboard, copy-paste

I am wondering, how can I copy a `char*` buffer to the Windows Clipboard and get the correct/wanted output like shown below?

Example:

I have a `char*` buffer that I put this into:

```
Text\nText text \ntext
```

We expect that when we copy it to the clipboard and paste it into a document, it will end up like this:

```
Text
Text text 
text
```

But when I try to copy and paste it, the result is like this:

```
TextText text text
```

So, what can I do so that I get the result I want?

Here is the function I am using:

```
void clipBoard(const char* output)
{
    const size_t len = strlen(output) + 1;
    HGLOBAL hMem = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, len);
    memcpy(GlobalLock(hMem), output, len);
    GlobalUnlock(hMem);
    OpenClipboard(0);
    EmptyClipboard();
    SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, hMem);
    CloseClipboard();
}
```

Calling it like this:

```
clipBoard(buffer);
```

Comment: How and *where* do you "paste" the text? Remember that on Windows the standard newline is `"\r\n"`.

Comment: Show how you set up the buffer.

Comment: You will get the same result when doing this. `char * buffer /*Or string. Depending on what you want to call it*/= "Text\nText text \ntext"; `(Basically how i do it, only that it is a loger that ad a line when something heppends (That isent importent)) Than this `clipBoard(buffer);`

Comment: As @Someprogrammerdude says, the likely problem is that the recipient of the text is expecting newlines to be encoded as \r\n (CRLF), rather than just \n (LF), so try putting that in the buffer and see what results you get.

Comment: yeah, that works but the loger output with \n, so than i need to find a way to convert it to \r\n. And i cant just easly replace \n with \r\n becouse maby thay write \\n, than it isent suposed to make a new line.

Comment: @gofmode Replacing individual `'\n'` characters with `"\r\n"` strings will not replace `"\\n"` strings, which contain separate `'\'` and `'n'` characters, not `'\n'` characters.  Unless you are thinking of `"\\\n"`, which contains `'\'` and `'\n'` characters.

Answer (score 2):

Per the [Standard Clipboard Formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dataxchg/standard-clipboard-formats) documentation:

> CF_TEXT
>   1
>
> Text format. **Each line ends with a carriage return/linefeed (CR-LF) combination**. A null character signals the end of the data. Use this format for ANSI text.
>
> ...
>
> CF_UNICODETEXT
>   13
>
> Unicode text format. **Each line ends with a carriage return/linefeed (CR-LF) combination**. A null character signals the end of the data.

So, you need to replace all bare-LF (`\n`) characters with CRLF (`\r\n`) sequences instead.

```
Text\r\nText text \r\ntext
```